# I am using laravel to display the item in view page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, rbac

The code was in tab and code is:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="biography">
                        <p>{!! $artist{'description'} !!}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="exhibition">
                        <table class="table table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Title</th>
                                <th>Year</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                            @foreach($artist{'exhibition'} as $exhibition_history)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{!! $exhibition_history{'title'} !!}</td>
                                    <td>{!! $exhibition_history{'year'} !!}</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

here description is shown in view page but exhibition title and history is not shown when user is logged in..

and if user is not logged in they can view both description and exhibition..
can anybody tell me the proper solution for this..
i am using rbac

Comment: Please provide more information. Have you set up a middleware?
Please post your controller/repositories.

Comment: Need to specify more information not enough to answer?